# How to set correct image path from server in expo and react native

Tags: react-native, expo

I am using expo and ImagePicker. I have uploaded files to server (my local machine) but when I try to show the files on my iPhone there is nothing. I got the path but the component does not work.

My path is

```
"http://127.0.0.1:8086/storage/avatars/17/1396229C-A76B-42CD-9F15-D6F2E223D531.jpg",
```

and the Avatar component

```
            <Avatar
                size={120}
                rounded
                onPress={this.onAvatarChange}
                icon={{name: 'user', type: 'font-awesome'}}
                source={{
                    uri: this.state.avatar ? this.state.avatar : 'null',
                }}
                showAccessory
                containerStyle={styles.avatar}
            />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `localhost` or `http://127.0.0.1` check your computer's IP address and use it to replace the localhost.
You'll then have something like: `http:**191.178.14.11**:8086/storage/avatars/17/1396229C-A76B-42CD-9F15-D6F2E223D531.jpg`
That works for me.